# jQuery Tabs not showing the Asp Panel inside the selected Tab on PostBack

Tags: jquery, asp.net, tabs, updatepanel, web-parts

Here's the story:

I have 2 update panels. UpdatePanel 1 has a dropdownlist that has its own functionality. UpdatePanel2 has the Divs for the jQuery Tabs functionality.

Here are the code snippets:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="LabelColumn">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Company"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="CompanyDropDownList" runat="server" Width="300px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CompanyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul style="width: 200px">
                <li><a href="#MultiPurposeForm">Multi Purpose Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="#LeaveApplicationForm">Application For Leave</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="MultiPurposeForm">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style3">
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelHeader" runat="server" Text="Multi Purpose Form"></asp:Label>

                            <asp:Panel ID="MultiPurposeFormPanel" runat="server" Visible="True" OnLoad="MultiPurposeFormPanel_Load1">
                                <!-- Many controls come here -->
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div id="LeaveApplicationForm">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Application for Leave"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args)
    {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            //$("#dialog").dialog();
        });
    }

</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void CompanyDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ClearEmployeeDetails(true);
            this.ListEmployeesCheckBox.Checked = false;
            this.EmployeeSelectionDropDownList.Visible = false;

            if (this.CheckLoggedInUserForHRCoordinator())
            {
                this.ListEmployeesCheckBox.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.ListEmployeesCheckBox.Enabled = false;
                this.EmployeeSelectionDropDownList.Visible = false;
            }
        }


protected void MultiPurposeFormPanel_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.PopulateMPDocumentCategories();
        }

        private void PopulateMPDocumentCategories()
        {
            if (this.MPDocumentCategoryDropDownList.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MultiPurposeDocumentEntityService documentService =
                new MultiPurposeDocumentEntityService();

                MultiPurposeDocumentCollection documentCollection =
                    documentService.GetAll();

                foreach (var document in documentCollection)
                {
                    this.MPDocumentCategoryDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(document.Title,
                        document.Id.ToString()));
                }

                if (this.MPDocumentCategoryDropDownList.Items.Count != 0)
                {
                    this.PopulateMPDocumentList(this.MPDocumentCategoryDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);
                }
            }
        }
```

When the page loads for the first time, everything works fine. However after I select an item in the UpdatePanel1's dropdownlist, I am unable to see the MultiPurposeFormPanel. I can only see the LabelHeader.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like you're doing the right thing, using pageLoad to re-init the tab control.. can you post the code-behind as well ?

Comment: @sh1rts Hi, I have posted the code behind.. please let me know if you need anything else as well.. The code behind just adds few items to the drop down lists.

Comment: Hmm looks ok to me ? Can you do two things - 1) put an alert or a console.log('hello') in your pageLoad() function, and then 2) open your browser's debugger and see what's going on in the console and in the network trace, when you select an item in the CompanyDropDown. What do you see ?

Comment: @sh1rts Found the issue.. I had a `code` this.MultiPurposePanel.Visible = false; `code` which was getting triggers with every postback hence the tab was disappearing.

Thanks anyways Buddy :-)!

Answer (score 0):

Had a set visible = false triggers every postback. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: hehe :) no worries mate, sometimes you only see the answer after trying to explain your code to some random dude on the interweb :)

Comment: @sh1rts He he I guess its true :-)!